# uWebSockets - push events to server

Tags: node.js, websocket, client

I have a uWebSockets server as it seems to be a lot more performance friendly than socket.io servers.
So I have a server and its connected fine and after some trouble I got the index.html client side to connect, but now I'm not able to push events to the server from the client side. What am I doing wrong?

```
var WebSocketServer = require('uws').Server,
    express         = require('express'),
    path            = require('path'),
    app             = express(),
    server          = require('http').createServer(),
    createEngine    = require('node-twig').createEngine;

var wss = new WebSocketServer({server: server});

wss.on('connection', function (ws) {

    ws.on('join', function (value) {
        console.log('SOMEONE JUST JOINED');
    });

    ws.on('close', function () {
        //console.log('stopping client interval');
        clearInterval(id);
    });
});

server.on('request', app);

server.listen(8080, function () {
    console.log('Listening on http://localhost:8080');
});
```

index.html

```
<script>
      var host = window.document.location.host.replace(/:.*/, '');
      var server = new WebSocket('ws://' + host + ':8080');
      server.onmessage = function (event) {
        updateStats(JSON.parse(event.data));
      };

      server.onopen = function (event) {
        server.send("Here's some text that the server is urgently awaiting!");
        server.send('join');
      };

      function something() {
        console.log('WORKED');
        server.send('join');
      }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have an event listener setup on the server side that does receive and react on the message. Like

```
ws.on('message', function (msg) {
    // Do something with the message received from the client
});
```

Comment: hi there. 
I did have 
ws.on('join', function (value) {
        console.log('SOMEONE JUST JOINED');
    });
is on('message') the global way of sending data to the server? 
I'm speaking from experience in socket.io where on server or client i code

(server or client side) socket.on('handler_name', cb) 
and 
(server or client side) socket.emit('handler_name', data);

Comment: Thank you very much for you help

Comment: I think there is no `join` since websockets don't a concept of a group or session other than due to the connection. uws directly exposes a websocket interface and not a high level framework API like socket.io. Therefore they are not directly comparable and will not utilize the same API. You should look up how the uws API works. Afaik it's also the same one as the API for the node.js `ws` module.

Comment: Yeah your right. when i say 'join' it could be anything. the join is a custom emitter name on either the server or the client side. Socket.io has this feature and thats the reason i though i could use i here. The only thing that works is sending 'message' and receiving 'message' either client or server side. which sucks really but ill have to make do as the performance really is a lot better than socket io. I barged my server with a 1000 connections and socket io crashed

Comment: but with this implementation i got 10,000 connections

Comment: @TheMan68 do you have any example to implement `uws` in nodejs, or any other resourceful link. I'm looking it from a while.

Comment: ill have to look into it but personally i wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: i find node a little inadequate in comparison to a php site etc. I decided to move from a node based site back to a symfony site